# Why is Azure DevOps Release Transforming Web.config

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Pipeline set up with continuous integration.  In my Release I dont have transformation enabled.  Source code has a web.config, web.debug.config and web.release.config.  I just want the deployed to use web.config.  I thought by not enabling transformation it would just values in web.config.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task is not responsible for performing the transforms for `*.debug.config` and `*.release.config` into your `web.config` file. This is handled by msbuild in your csproj file when you compile the solution in *Release* or *Debug* configurations.

For example, compiling your solution locally with the release parameter will accomplish the same result that you're seeing in your build pipeline:

```
msbuild mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

The File Transforms task is responsible for performing *additional transforms* that map to config files that correspond to your pipeline's stages. Eg `web.Staging.config` or `web.Production.config` where your pipeline has *Staging* and *Production* stages. This is accomplished by enabling the *Xml transformation* option.

In addition to performing these transformations, it can also inject values from your pipeline variables into those files when you select the *XML variable substitution* option. To leverage this option, the [documentation outlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution-example) that you must represent the values in the config file with a `__VARIABLE-NAME__` syntax.

Comment: Best explanation. Thanks for the link, it was very useful to understand the steps.